# Jenkins Pipeline powershell step fails due to "powershell not found"

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins server running v2.107.3, and a Windows agent node. A simple test powershell pipeline is failing because it can't find "powershell".

Here's my test pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                powershell(script:'Write-Output Hello')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the response from the agent is always:

```
C:\Jenkins\workspace\test_ps_remoting@tmp\durable-ccca47a5\powershellWrapper.ps1 : The term 'powershell' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Jenkins\workspace\test_ps_remoting@tmp\durable-ccca47a5\powershellHelper.ps1:54 char:9
+     & { & $MainScript | Out-FileNoBom -Writer $OutputWriter } *>&1 |  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (powershell:String) [powershellWrapper.ps1], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,powershellWrapper.ps1
```

I've managed to grab a copy of the files in @tmp as they run, and if I execute the steps manually, it seems to work just fine:

```
. .\powershellHelper.ps1
Execute-AndWriteOutput -MainScript .\powershellWrapper.ps1 -OutputFile out.txt -LogFile log.txt -ResultFile result.txt
```

Creates the files expected, with the "result" of `0` and the log of `Hello`.

Comment: It sounds like your environment variables are bad.  Fully-path `powershell.exe`. Also: `& { & $` just.. why?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That's nothing to do with me. That's what the powershell plugin puts in place. I just specfied `powershell('write-host hello')`. The rest is wrapper guff.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 your tip about the ENV was spot-on. I added an `PATH = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"` to the pipeline seems to have fixed it. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Their boilerplate is very bizarre, but meh.  I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error, the process likely can't find the powershell executable, meaning it's

1. Not fully pathed
2. Not in the PATH environment variable

If you fix either of these, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Weirdly, there is a system-level PATH entry for Powershell, but the the java process doesn't seem to be getting it. For now, setting it in my pipeline solves the problem.

Comment: @Cylindric It sounds like it isn't reading the SYSTEM environment variables, just USER and/or PROCESS.  (Three tiers of headache)

Comment: I've had to un-accept this answer, because I realised that I can't really set a global PATH in a multi-agent pipeline because I don't want to mess   with other agent settings, and they're not even all Windows Agents. I also suspect I'll never get an answer to a question that isn't open.

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out another of the Jenkins admins has put in a _global_ environment variable setting PATH to `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`. That was fun.